# Column not found in dbase file

Tags: db2, spatial

When I try to import a shapefile using db2se, I specify the input columns to be loaded in the syntax as the COLUMN NAME

```
db2se import_shape <dbname> -userId <username>
-pw <password> -fileName <shapefile to be loaded> -inputAttrColumns N(Cat_Zones) -srsName WGS84_SRS_1003 -tableSchema GEXPDBA -tableName TPOLYGON_STAGING -tableAttrColumns VC_FLD_1 -createTableFlag 0 -spatialColumn POLYGON_OB -typeSchema db2gse -typeName st_multipolygon -messagesFile C:\ABC1.txt -client 1

GSE2112N  The column "CAT_ZONES" cannot be found in the dBASE file.
```

But if I replace it with the POSITIONAL parameter, it works.

```
db2se import_shape <dbname> -userId <username>
-pw <password> -fileName <shapefile to be loaded> -inputAttrColumns P(1) -srsName WGS84_SRS_1003 -tableSchema GEXPDBA -tableName TPOLYGON_STAGING -tableAttrColumns VC_FLD_1 -createTableFlag 0 -spatialColumn POLYGON_OB -typeSchema db2gse -typeName st_multipolygon -messagesFile C:\ABC1.txt -client 1

GSE0000I  The operation was completed successfully.
```

Any reason why this would happen. The shapefile info is as below.

```
db2se shape_info -filename <shapefile to be loaded>

Shape file information
----------------------
File code                  = 9994
File length (16-bit words) = 2533850
Shape file version         = 1000
Shape type                 = 5 (ST_MULTIPOLYGON)
Number of records          = 2636

Minimum X coordinate = -173.109762
Maximum X coordinate = -66.954002
Minimum Y coordinate = 18.915497
Maximum Y coordinate = 71.398048
Shapes do not have Z coordinates.
Shapes do not have M coordinates.

Shape index file (extension .shx) is present.

Attribute file information
--------------------------
dBase file code                = 3
Date of last update            = 2013-09-03
Number of records              = 2636
Number of bytes in header      = 97
Number of bytes in each record = 305
Number of columns              = 2

Column Number  Column Name      Data Type       Length  Decimal
-------------  ---------------  --------------  ------  -------
            1  Cat_Zones        C ( Character)     254        0
            2  Country          C ( Character)      50        0

Coordinate system definition: "GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",DATUM["D_WGS_1984",SPHEROID
["WGS_1984",6378137.0,298.257223563]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.01
74532925199433],METADATA["World",-180.0,-90.0,180.0,90.0,0.0,0.0174532925199433,
0.0,1262]]"
```

Comment: May be because of case sensitivity? Try quoting the column name, something like `...  -inputAttrColumns N(\"Cat_Zones\")...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was a case sensitivity issue. Using `inputAttrColumns N(\"Cat_Zones\")` solved the problem.